# Android Worker doWork() runs into for-loop

Tags: android, worker

I see from Server side that Android calls multiple /test API requests - looks like never-ending for loop.
This API is defined only in TestWorker class:

```
class TestWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        callApiRequest()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun callApiRequest() {
        XUseCase.execute()
            .backgroundToMainThread() 
            .subscribe(
                { ->
                    ..
                },
                {
                    ..
                }
            )
    }    

    companion object {
        const val REPEAT_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS = 3L
    }
}

private fun initTestWorker() {
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

    val workerRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<TestWorker>(TestWorker.REPEAT_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()

    WorkManager
        .getInstance(this)
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, workerRequest)
}
```

initTestWorker() gets called in MyApp onCreate() method. I'm not sure how, but maybe someone has experienced similar behaviour, from the front end I can not reproduce the issue. Any loop experiences using Worker?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use Periodic work requests? You could use one time request if you want it to get executed once?

Comment: It's needed to be executed every x hours.

Comment: Please once check and confirm the retry policy of your HTTP request client.

Comment: If that's okay then try using a listenable worker  to validate if task is completed to tell worker to sleep till the next iteration, so it may stop retrying your call logic